# docker run passing environment variables with whitespaces

Tags: dockerfile, robotframework

I have a `Dockerfile` which is trying to call a Robot Framework test runner. I am passing desired command line arguments (e. g. testcases, testsuit, included tags, excluded tags, etc.) to the `Dockerfile` as environment variables. Sometimes my command line arguments contains whitespaces. For example consider my testcase to be `Define Something` and my testsuite to be `MyWebsite`. If I set my environments as *TESTCASE='Define Sponsor'* and *TESTSUITE=MyWebsite*, I will get this error from Robot Framework test runner:

```
[ ERROR ] Suite 'Scenarios' contains no tests named ''Define or Something'' in suite 'MyWebsite'.
```

I tried multiple ways to pass my environments:

1. Using env file:

   `docker run --env-file test/test.env`

   Where `test/test.env` contains:

   `TESTSUITE="MyWebsite"`

   `TESTCASE="Define Sponsor"`
2. Set them in the shell:

   `TESTSUITE="MyWebsite"`

   `TESTCASE="Define Sponsor"`
3. Set them in the `Dockerfile`:

   `ENV TESTSUITE="MyWebsite"`

   `ENV TESTCASE="Define Sponsor"`

All of them returned mentioned error.

Comment: Have you tried `TESTCASE="DefineSponsor"` or `TESTCASE="Define_Sponsor"`? To do any more diagnosis I think we would need to see how you're actually calling robot.

Comment: @BryanOakley, yes; I tried `TESTCASE="DefineSponsor"`. It worked completely fine.

Answer (score 3):

The error is kind of explicit here, especially this part: `contains no tests named ''Define or Something''`

Notice the `Define OR Something`. The CLI uses spaces as a separator, and so it thinks you're trying to select the test cases `Define` and `Something`. Instead, type `Define_Something` and Robot Framework will correctly convert the underscore to a space, but after the CLI and it's separators were evaluated, which should correctly select your test case, `Define Something`

This is documented [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-suite-name-and-documentation)

> possible underscores are replaced with spaces, and names fully in lower case are title cased. For example, some_tests.html becomes Some Tests and My_test_directory becomes My test directory.

Comment: I don't know what is robotframework, but is there a workaround for this in Docker natively?